# Why is the value incremented when assigned?

Tags: java

I'm making a GUI for the game (Open Gl). That is, I have a Gui Screen on which other components are added. So I wanted to make all other GUIs move to the left relative to the original position of GuiScreen. It works but not as I wanted simply contrary to logic.

Here i have this situation (this code runs in onUpdate(), just do every frame):

```
private void moveRelativeContent(Gui guiContent)
{
    guiContent.position.x = guiContent.startPosition.x + this.position.x();
    guiContent.position.y = guiContent.startPosition.y + this.position.y();
}
```

As you can see I'm just using assignment. That is, I assign the content position from the `List<Gui>` to the sum of the original content position plus the current GuiScreen position. That is `guiContent.position` needs each frame always be `guiContent.startPosition + this.position;`. It's logical. But for me it's work very strange. I have every frame `guiContent.position` increases. It's like he's using the `+=` command instead of the `=` command.

Values before method:

```
Before: ScreenPosX: 0.02
Before: Current Gui PosX: 0.0039999485
Before: Current Gui Start PosX: 0.0039999485
```

Values after method:

```
After: ScreenPos: 0.02
After: Current Gui PosX: 0.023999948
After: Current Gui Start PosX: 0.023999948
```

First look in my initialized `GameObject` code (include `Gui`s):

```
public GameObject(float posX, float posY, float posZ, 
                    float rotX, float rotY, float rotZ, 
                        float scaleX, float scaleY, float scaleZ) 
{
    this();
    ...

    this.startPosition = new Vector3f(posX, posY, posZ);
    this.startRotation = new Vector3f(rotX, rotY, rotZ);
    this.startScale    = new Vector3f(scaleX, scaleY, scaleZ);
    this.position = this.startPosition;
    this.rotation = this.startRotation;
    this.scale    = this.startScale;

    ...
}
```

Here another version's of this constructor:

```
public GameObject(Vector3f position, Vector3f rotation, Vector3f scale) 
{
    this(position.x(), position.y(), position.z(), 
         rotation.x(), rotation.y(), rotation.z(), 
           scale.x() ,   scale.y() ,  scale.z() );
}

public GameObject(Vector2f position, Vector2f rotation, Vector2f scale) 
{
    this(position.x(), position.y(), 
         rotation.x(), rotation.y(), 
           scale.x() ,  scale.y() );
}
```

Next where started updated `GuiScreen`. This code, from my `Scene` and `WorldScene.class` in main `onUpdate()`:

```
@Override
public abstract void onUpdate(); // in Scene

@Override
public void onUpdate() // in WorldScene
{
    if(!this.isInGamePause)
    {
        ... this some in-game code
        this.client.selectedGuiScreen.close(); // close once

    }
    else if(this.isInGamePause)
    {
        ...
        this.client.selectedGuiScreen.open();  // open once
        this.client.selectedGuiScreen.onUpdate();
    }

    ...

    this.updateFrameTime();
    this.client.getGameWindow().updateViewport();
    this.client.getGameWindow().updateWindow();

    ...
}
```

Next step its my `GuiScreen.class` ``onUpdate()``` method:

```
public GameObject onUpdate() 
{
    for(Gui guiContent : this.allContent)
    {
        guiContent.onUpdate();

        if(guiContent.getId() == 0)
        {
            SimplePrint.message("Before: ScreenPosX: " + this.position.x);
            SimplePrint.message("Before: Current Gui PosX: " + guiContent.position.x);
            SimplePrint.message("Before: Current Gui Start PosX: " + guiContent.startPosition.x);
        }

        this.moveRelaviteContent(guiContent);

        if(guiContent.getId() == 0)
        {
            SimplePrint.message("After: ScreenPos: " + this.position.x);
            SimplePrint.message("After: Current Gui PosX: " + guiContent.position.x);
            SimplePrint.message("After: Current Gui Start PosX: " + guiContent.startPosition.x);
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }

    return this;
}
```

And finally if who interested my `guiContent.onUpdate()` :

```
@Override
public GameObject onUpdate() 
{
    if(this.scale.x() <= 0) this.scale.x = 0.2f;
    if(this.scale.y() <= 0) this.scale.y = 0.2f;

    if(this.scale.x() >= 2) this.scale.x = 2f;
    if(this.scale.y() >= 2) this.scale.y = 2f;

    //this.rotateGui();
    return super.onUpdate();
}
```

Ps: Immediately say that mistakes in other methods I have no. I just double-checked 100 times.

And most interesting the that I in test project tested and `guiContent.position = guiContent.startPosition + this.position;` worked as I intended. Please help and the I already 3 day not can understand in than the problem.

Comment: This is way too less information to find the source of your issue. It is maybe enough to get a rough idea of what you are observing, but you completelty left out all the relevant details that play a role here. Your question is likely to get closed for being too broad if it stays like this. Please see [ask], thanks.

Comment: I know this is very less info but, in your opinion what could trigger this bug?

Comment: Please try to provide a [MCVE] that reproduces the issue. Please tell us the values of `guiContent.position`, `guiContent.startPosition` and `this.position` before and after your method.

Comment: This is not about opinions, because there could be hundreds of different reasons. You should add the relevant and necessary code so that we can pinpoint the problem. Or you need to learn [how to use a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: *"I know this is very less info but, in your opinion what could trigger this bug?"* This is not how SO works. SO is not a forum to opinionate about bugs, it's a programming Q&A. Your question is supposed to be useful for other people. Our answers are supposed to be useful for other people. That on the way we might help you solve an issue you have is a nice side effect, but not the purpose.

Comment: Ok @MaxVollmer wait 2 min

Comment: *"My project is too big to write all information here."* The **minimal** in [MCVE] is there for a reason. *Please* **read** the links we provide you here. In no way have you read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [MCVE] and all the referenced links in those articles in the time that it took you to respond to Zabuza and me.

Comment: *"wait 2 min"* <- Please don't rush. We don't run away, take your time to read the help pages on SO, read other questions with high upvote count, and then take the rest of the day to rewrite your question properly. Good luck!

Comment: ```[12:34:02]: [Client thread/INFO]: [Craftix]: Before: ScreenPosX: 0.02
[12:34:02]: [Client thread/INFO]: [Craftix]: Before: Current Gui PosX: 0.0039999485
[12:34:02]: [Client thread/INFO]: [Craftix]: Before: Current Gui Start PosX: 0.0039999485
[12:34:02]: [Client thread/INFO]: [Craftix]: After: ScreenPos: 0.02
[12:34:02]: [Client thread/INFO]: [Craftix]: After: Current Gui PosX: 0.023999948
[12:34:02]: [Client thread/INFO]: [Craftix]: After: Current Gui Start PosX: 0.023999948```

Comment: A don't how can increase ```startPosition``` if it not change

Comment: How do you initialize `guiContent.position` and `guiContent.startPosition`? Both are objects, so maybe you initialize them with the same object.

Comment: Yes position, startPosition, is Vector3f object where contains x, y, z values

Comment: @ThomasKläger i add it to post

Comment: You are assigning the same object to `startPosition` and `position`. Once you do that, if you change the values in that object, it is reflected both in `startPosition` and `position` because they are the same. You need to assign two different objects.

Comment: `this.position = this.startPosition;` In a language like C++ this would create a copy, in Java you simply have two references to the same object. Any change to `position` will change `startPosition` and vice versa, because they are the same instance of `Vector3f`. @ThomasKläger nailed it.

Comment: And tell me how then is better to do?

Comment: Just create a different object: `this.position = new Vector3f(posX, posY, posZ);`

Comment: But on top of all constructors i create this.position = new Vector3f(0,0,0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reduced your constructor to a minimum to show the problem with `this.position` and `this.startPosition`. The same problem exists with `this.rotation` and `this.scale` - you have to apply the solution for `this.position` also to these two fields...

```
public GameObject(float posX, float posY, float posZ, 
                float rotX, float rotY, float rotZ, 
                float scaleX, float scaleY, float scaleZ) 
{
    this();
    this.position = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0); // 1
    this.startPosition = new Vector3f(posX, posY, posZ); // 2
    this.position = this.startPosition;  // 3
}
```

On line `// 1` you create a `Vector3f` (A) and assign a reference to it to `this.position`.

On line `// 2` you create another `Vector3f` (B) and assign a reference to it to `this.startPosition`.

On line `// 3` you overwrite the reference to `Vector3f` (A) that has been stored in `this.position` with the reference to `Vector3f` (B) that you stored in `this.startPosition`.

From this point on `this.position` references the same `Vector3f` as `this.startPosition`, so `this.position.x` is just another name for `this.startPosition.x` (both refer to the same memory location).

---

To fix your problem you must assign a clone of `this.startPosition` to `this.position`

```
public GameObject(float posX, float posY, float posZ, 
                float rotX, float rotY, float rotZ, 
                float scaleX, float scaleY, float scaleZ) 
{
    this();
    this.position = new Vector3f(0, 0, 0); // 1
    this.startPosition = new Vector3f(posX, posY, posZ); // 2
    this.position = new Vector3f(this.startPosition);  // 3
}
```

Now, line `// 3` creates a new, independent `Vector3f` that happens to have the same starting values as the one referenced by `this.startPosition`.

Comment: Okay i got it! Thanks!

Comment: I’m already offended that already in Open Gl I rummage well, but at such a moment I blunted